# Why is my WordPress website using page link indexing with '/?p=123', and how can I resolve this issue?

Tags: wordpress, yoast, google-indexing-api

My website has many pages indexed with URLs like '/?p=123'.

Upon checking, all these URLs work correctly and redirect to the appropriate pages.

However, these URLs are not found in the sitemap. We have disabled the short link using the Yoast Premium Plugin.

If you have any ideas for a solution, please share them with us. Thank you in advance.

These URLs are not found in the sitemap. We have disabled the short link using the Yoast Premium Plugin.

Also, Yoast Premium support give status is not any issues from our side, please check the google forum for more support.